# Create Profile Information Page in PHP/MySQL/PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi I am having an issue creating a profile page using PDO- I can get the one to work that is in the old mysql but I can't figure out how to change the data over to PDO- I have been at this for weeks now and just at a loss. Please be nice I am VERY new to all of this. Here is the code that works- the old way

```
<?php
 require_once('connection.php');
 $id=$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
 $result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM member where mem_id='$id'");
 while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
 { 
 $fname=$row3['fname'];
 $lname=$row3['lname'];
 $address=$row3['address'];
 $contact=$row3['contact'];
 $picture=$row3['picture'];
 $gender=$row3['gender'];
 }
 ?>
```

And this is what I have tried to come up with but I just get a blank screen

```
<?php
require_once('connectpdo.php');
$id=$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];
$result3 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM member where mem_id='$id'");
$row3 = $stmt->fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
{ 
$fname=$row3['fname'];
$lname=$row3['lname'];
$address=$row3['address'];
$contact=$row3['contact'];
$picture=$row3['picture'];
$gender=$row3['gender'];
}
?>
```

The login works fine in both old MySql and in the PDO but I can not seem to get the user profile to come up in PDO

```
//Create query
    $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM  member WHERE username= :xtxt  AND password= :ztzt");
    $result->bindParam(':xtxt', $username);
    $result->bindParam(':ztzt', $password);
    $result->execute();
    $rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);


    //Check whether the query was successful or not
    if($rows > 0) {
            //Login Successful
            session_regenerate_id();
            $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['mem_id'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['firstname'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['password'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME'] = $member['username'];
            session_write_close();
            header("location: home.php");
            exit();
```

I get PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given in...from this line

```
$member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

I get  Undefined variable: stmt in ...& PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in...from this line

```
$row3 = $stmt->fetch (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

As I mentioned before I am very new at this, and I have spent many weeks researching doing multiple tutorials, and trying to figure all this out. I was just learning MySql when I was getting the depreciated errors and now I'm switching over to PDO, I know in the future I will need to pull information from multiple databases for one logged in user. I am not using functions or classes. Thanks in advance, my dogs will appreciate your help.

Comment: You're using `$result = $conn->prepare(...` which you say works, but you're also using `$result3 = $db->prepare(...` which should most likely be `$result3 = $conn->prepare(`

Comment: Plus, you're mixing a `mysql_` function `$member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);` with PDO. **They do not mix.** This isn't rum & coke.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I know I am mixing mysql and PDO this line of code $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); I am trying to figure out the equivalent in PDO

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved it! I am going to post the code for any one else having this issue @Fred, Thanks!

And I do know that the code is really different because I managed to get it on my test site, in my login process page I changed this code:

```
// query
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE username=:hjhjhjh AND  customers_password= :asas");
$result->bindParam(':hjhjhjh', $username);
$result->bindParam(':asas', $customers_password);
$result->execute();
$rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
if($rows > 0) {
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['customers_id']=$row['customers_id'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_CUSTOMERS_KENNEL'];//kwaon ang id sang may tyakto nga username kag password 
    header("location: http://localhost:8888/ShowMyDog/newtemplate/index.php?action=account");
}
```

And in the page I wanted the profile to show up I changed the code to:

```
<?Php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
    echo "Welcome to the member's area, " . $_SESSION['username'] . "!";
} else {
    echo "Please log in first to see this page.";
}
?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?Php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE | E_CORE_ERROR);
require "config.php"; // Database connection details. 
$customers_id=$_SESSION['loggedin']; // Collecting one record with for user
$count=$dbo->prepare("select * from customers where customers_id=:customers_id");
$count->bindParam(":customers_id",$customers_id,PDO::PARAM_INT,1);

if($count->execute()){
echo " Success <br>";
$row = $count->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($row);
echo "<hr>";
echo "<br>Admin id = $row[customers_id]";
echo "<br>username = $row[username]";
echo "<br>password=$row[customers_password]";
echo "<br>kennel=$row[customers_kennel]";
echo "<br>first name=$row[customers_firstname]"; 
echo "<br>last name=$row[customers_lastname]";
echo "<br>email address=$row[customers_email_address]";
echo "<br> postcode=$row[customers_postcode]";
echo "<br> street address=$row[customers_street_address]";
echo "<br> gender=$row[customers_gender]";
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

I know it is still a bit messy, but like I said I'm new at this